# Spring Security: don't redirect to login page in case unauthorised

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have Spring Security with oAuth2 authorisation.

I use it for REST API.

My configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/health").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

I need to make all requests return me `401` when I didn't authorise.

But now when I'm not authorised I got redirect to `/login` page.

I need to use it like usual REST API: if I did authorise then get content, otherwise get 401 Unauthorised.

How I can make it?

Thanks in addition for help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to configure an `AuthenticationEntryPoint` which is invoked when Spring Security detects a non-authenticated request. Spring also gives you a handy implementation which enables you to return whatever `HttpStatus` you need:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            //rest of your config...
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));

}
```